# keras scalar multiplication using inputs

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I just want to do scalar multiplication using inputs

```
int_input = Input(shape=(1,), name='depth')
int_sigmoid = (Activation('sigmoid')(depthInput))
imageInput = Input(shape=(100, 100, 1), name='image')
imageInputNormalized = BatchNormalization()(imageInput)
con1 = Conv2D(64, (2, 2), padding='same', name='con1')(Activation('relu')(imageInputNormalized))
mp1 = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2)(con1)
con2 = Conv2D(128, (2, 2), padding='same', name='con2')(Activation('relu')(mp1))
l1 = Lambda(lambda x: x ** depthSigmoid)(con2)
```

i get error

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [20,50,50,128] vs. [20,1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code sample seems to be incomplete, or possibly I'm missing where a number of variables are defined. I would consider adding more of your code.

What I do notice in your last line, you do not perform scalar multiplication. `**` is not used for scalar multiplication, that might need to be changed to `*`.

Hope this helps and good luck solving your problem!

Comment: Good answer. Just to add,  `x ** depthSigmoid` raises 'x' to the power of 'depthSigmoid': `2 ** 3`.

Comment: you are right about that but still have the same error